# How is it possible to send multiple POST requests over a single TCP connection (Java)?

Tags: java, rest, sockets, http, tcp

I have a Spring Boot application running on Wildfly. A colleague is using curl to send a couple of files to my server.
When he sends the files, and we look at Wireshark, the two post requests are sent in the same frame.
My server processes them separately, reading the socket, saving the file, then closing the connection. Both requests get processed correctly.
How is this?

My guess is that when I close the connection in my code it's not closing the `TCP` connection, it's just finishing the `HTTP` request, but the actual socket remains open and the details are hidden from me. Is that correct?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection. You're never dealing with TCP or Socket connections in servlet code. only with servlet request, responses, and their streams.

Comment: Thank you! I feel I knew that. I'm spending too much time at the top of the stack these days! :-)  Care to write an answer?